# Configuration file by absolute path Log4j2.xml 2.4.1 and AOP protect classes to avoid proxy by hacking

Tags: spring, tomcat, aop, java-7, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 2.4.1 version for AOP around to log any method public and not static by aspectjrt library and aspectjveawer and it works fine on Tomcat8 (J2EE 1.7.0_80-b15) and servlet 3.1

I have 2 problems that I didn't find a solution searching in google.

1. I need to specify the **full path of log4j2.xml configuration file** in a specific path in the production server different of tomcat path webapp for security reason of infrastructure.
2. I need to avoid to some **hacker** after hack the server **change pointcut** defined in applicationContext.xml and **advice by around the SecurityManager class that decrypt in runtime any username/password of service used** (db, ws with secutiry, ftps, ...)

Somebody have some info to solve this two problem?

Thanks a lot for your support.

I imaged that Spring and AspectJ had defined a Security level to avoid to proxy specified classes to get sensible information. I saw that in Proxy class of Spring exist two **setter setFrozen** and **setOpaque** if I remember right.

Thanks a lot to any help...

Ciao

Comment: Better is to encrypt the db passwords with Jasypt and then insert them in your applicationContext.xml. Also, if your server is already compromised, then the hacker will without a doubt download the DB and try to brute-force into it.

Comment: I use exactly this method by Jasypt but if an hacker get control of server can modify pointcut of aop, restart the server and get username/passoword from log file...

Comment: Okay, good, but to be honest, I don't understand your 2nd point, the framing of sentence seems weird. Especially 'advice by around the SecurityManager class that decrypt in runtime any username/password of service used . '. Also, if you are worried about it, then you can always move to a Java based config, it would make the task more difficult for the attacker as everything will be in class files. Lastly, this is more like an end-game preparation, I hope you have done that much work to prevent an attack from succeeding.

Comment: I like to do the things to avoid problem so every thing was done right... ;)

Comment: About first question do you know a solution ? Thanks a lot

Comment: It's incredible If I set in server.xml or catalina.properties the parameter log4jConfiguration don't load the configuration file of log4j2.
But If I set it with file:/// in web.xml it works.
Why isn't work in this mode?
I need to load it by catalina.properties as requested by infrastructure team to control access on configuration web apps.
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

See also the [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html) , you can set system property `log4j.configurationFile` to `path/to/log4j2.xml`.

If each web app has a different config, put the log4j2 jars (api, core and web, all three!) in your WEB-INF/lib and specify the path to log4j2.xml in the web.xml with servlet context parameter `log4jConfiguration`. See the log4j [web apps manual page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) for details.

Note that log4j-2.4.1 has a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-873) that you can work around by setting the display name in your web.xml.

Comment: It's incredible If I set in server.xml or catalina.properties the parameter log4jConfiguration don't load the configuration file of log4j2.
But If I set it with file:/// in web.xml it works.
Why isn't work in this mode?
I need to load it by catalina.properties as requested by infrastructure team to control access on configuration web apps.
Could somebody help me?

Comment: In catalina.properties you must use key `log4j.configurationFile`. This will be a global log4j config file for all web apps in that Tomcat instance...